# Calculate regression coefficients for individuals (low sample size regression)?

Tags: r, regression, clustering

Is there a way to calculate the regression coefficients for individuals instead of just a group resp. calculating regression coefficients for a very small sample size?

**Background**

My goal is to test different ways to cluster/segment a group of people. In the domain in question the best variables to use for segmentation would be variables that best express the importance an individual places on certain attributes.

However I do not have direct measurement of that importance. What I do have is an indirect measurement for the whole sample based on a shapley value regression of attribute ratings and final respondent choice.

Clearly put, I asked a couple of people how they would rate the attributes of a given brand and which brand they would choose in the end.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to obtain this indirect importance measurement also on an individual level which would mean either:

- Extracting individual coefficient estimators from the overall regression model ( I don't believe that is possible)
- Calculating a regression for each individual (Don't know how to do that hence the question)

**Problem and what I tried**

I work in `R` and I do know how to fit a grouped linear model. As all my respondents rated two brands I do have n = 2 per group.

However fitting a normal grouped linear model results in unusable results where almost all coefficients are NA and one or two equal 1. Additionally I would prefer to fit a relative importance or shapley value regression but the `relaimpo` package throws an error complaining about too few observations.

What other avenues could I pursue?

**Update:**

I have been using this code so far:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(i_TAN) %>%
  do(model = lm(formula = Consideration ~ ., data = .))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ben Norris found out that the `relaimpo` packages has a hard minimum number of observations, so if I wanted to pursue this path I have to up my sample size.

As I only have the data that I have, I pursued a "hacky" solution which I am going to describe for completionists sake. The steps were as follows:

1. Assign each individual to one of `k` groups randomly, so that `n/k > 4` (with n being the total sample size)
2. Repeat this step `i` couple of times,so that each individual is assigned to `i`groups
3. Split the total data set into a list of  `k` dfs along the groups
4. Train a regression model with `relaimpo` for each data set
5. Average the resulting coefficients over all groups an individual was a part of to get approximate "individual coefficients"

This is a rather unscientific process but seemed better to me than simply "duplicating" individuals answers until the minimum sample size was met.

Here is the code I used:

````r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(relaimpo)

#create groups
df %>%
  add_count(i_TAN) %>%
group_by(i_TAN) %>%
  mutate(
    g1 = as.integer(runif(n, 1, 51)),
    g2 = as.integer(runif(n, 1, 51)),
    g3 = as.integer(runif(n, 1, 51)),
    g4 = as.integer(runif(n, 1, 51))
  ) %>%
  {.} -> df

# Create all dfs
df %>%
  select(i_TAN,g1,g2,g3,g4) %>%
  gather(nam,group,-i_TAN) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  select(-nam) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "i_TAN") %>%
  select(1:35) %$%
  split(.,group) %>%
  {.} -> list_of_df

lapply(list_of_df, function(x) { x["group"] <- NULL; x }) %>%
  lapply(function(x) { x["i_TAN"] <- NULL; x }) %>%
  {.} -> list_of_modelDF

# Fit all models
lapply(list_of_modelDF,function(x){lm(Consideration~.,data = x)}) -> list_of_reg

lapply(list_of_reg,function(x){relaimpo::calc.relimp(object = x, type = c("lmg"), rela = TRUE)}) -> list_of_relaimpo
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing you want with the `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `purrr` and `broom` packages. The key workflow sequence is to

```
1. group your data with `dplyr::group_by`
2. use `tidyr::nest` to generate a list column of data.frames
3. use `dplyr::mutate` and `purrr::map` to generate a list column containing the models
4. use `broom::tidy` to convert the model into a data.frame
5. use `tidyr::unnest` to convert the model parameters back into readable data. 



library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
# Setting up a simple example data.frame
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 X = runif(6),
                 Y = rnorm(6))
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, function(df) lm(X ~ Y, data = df))) %>%
  mutate(tidy = map(model, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(tidy))
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID data             model  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <dbl> <list>           <list> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [3 x 2]> <lm>   (Intercept)    0.453    0.0153    29.5    0.0215
2     1 <tibble [3 x 2]> <lm>   Y             -0.227    0.0128   -17.7    0.0360
3     2 <tibble [3 x 2]> <lm>   (Intercept)   -0.221    0.281     -0.787  0.576 
4     2 <tibble [3 x 2]> <lm>   Y              0.366    0.207      1.76   0.328
```

Comment: I tried out your exact example with the provided sample data but I get the following error ```Error in numeric(nrowz) : invalid 'length' argument``` which happens at the 1st ```mutate``` where we map the linear model.

Comment: @Fnguyen Based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523399/error-in-numericnrowz-invalid-length-argument-from-map-function, the `map` function is also defined in the `maps` package and produces that error with invalid data (for the maps package). I am running a clean session with just the four packages I mentioned loaded . Try using `purrr::map` everywhere I have `map`.

Comment: Thanks it was indeed the ```purr::map``` call. However sadly this does not solve my problem. Your solution is equivalent to the ```group_by``` and ```do(lm())``` I already did. This gets me to unusable results and cannot be adapted to ```relaimpo::calc``` which needs more observations.

Comment: I have played around with `relaimpo` and it seems the problem is inherent to its need for a minimum of four observations, which your data does not have. If you don't have My method at least extracts the coefficient estimators from the model.

Comment: thank you for your input. Finding out the minimum observations for relaimpo has guided me towards a possible solution path.